# How to check if a URL has a matching ending as a json string

Tags: javascript, json, url

So if my URL is "example.com/API?tags=test" and I have a json file with:

```
"Name": {
"main": "hello"
"tags": ["hello", "test"]
}
```

How do I check if the URL has the same tag as a json value and then print the json string?

Answer (score 0):

First [extract url variables](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/get-url-variables/), let'say you know have the desired value in `const tags`;

Then, using a json like

```
const data = {
  "Name": {
    "main": "hello"
    "tags": ["hello", "test"]
   }
};
```

`data['Name'].tags.some( t => t === tags);` gives you the boolean

Comment: I don't understand, does that check if the json tags has the one of the same as the url?

Comment: I check if there if the url has `?tags=hello` or `?tags=test`

Comment: I just did that -_-

Comment: does it print the JSON string?